# image swap not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I have an image swap routine that works nicely, but I have just noticed it fails in Safari.

```
    $("#image1, #image2").click(function(){
    switch(this.id)
    {
    case 'image1':
      _(this.id,"../../img/answers(biggest2).png","../../img/b6a(AC)ans.png");
      break;
    case 'image2':
      _(this.id,"../../img/suggestions2.png","../../img/b6b(AC)ans.png");
      break;
    }
    function _(id,main, alt){
    if($("#"+id).attr("src") == main) $("#"+id).attr("src", alt);
        else $("#"+id).attr("src", main);
    }
    });
```

Is there something obvious that Macs don't like about the above?

Is there perhaps a better crossbrowser solution?

Comment: I don't know about Macs, but personally I think the use of `_` as a method name should be a criminal offence :)

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Works fine in PC Safari as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/yb9NJ/ Does this fail on your Mac?

Comment: Try moving the function to above the switch, its also best to give it a name such as `toggleSrc()`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for creating the fiddle. Works fine in Safari 6.0.5 on OS X.

Comment: Yes TrueBlue the jsfiddle example works for me in Safari, so it's got to be something else. I'll report back when I nail it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have $(document).ready({...}); wrapped around your code? @TerryPeck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gareth Luckett rightly points out you should not define the method inside the event handler. As Anton points out you should have it in a loaded handler (modern version below). JSFiddle adds this for you, so you need to add it yourself.

Try declaring it outside the handler (as a global function)

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/yb9NJ/2/

```
$(function(){
    $("#image1, #image2").click(function () {
        switch (this.id) {
            case 'image1':
                flipit(this.id, "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_pkp85ufRHC4vy0uMXMLV6TyemIQViRFEZXbbfY1tkFR9fSOX", "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOMTLvVtzl2kG_Oz4ODC5uvRMuHtlTNM84rj2iFiGqgq77dKJQ-Q");
                break;
            case 'image2':
                flipit(this.id, src = "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_pkp85ufRHC4vy0uMXMLV6TyemIQViRFEZXbbfY1tkFR9fSOX", "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOMTLvVtzl2kG_Oz4ODC5uvRMuHtlTNM84rj2iFiGqgq77dKJQ-Q");
                break;
        }
    });
});
function flipit(id, main, alt) {
    if ($("#" + id).attr("src") == main) $("#" + id).attr("src", alt);
    else $("#" + id).attr("src", main);
}
```

Comment: It wasn't a Mac or Safari issue. It was lack of a loaded handler. So it didn't work anywhere. I just hadn't noticed I'd lost it somehow. I'll use your right side of the law version above :)